# Looking for javax.management.MXBean for Red5 on Android

Tags: android, red5, rtmp

I am currently working on an Android application that needs to publish a live stream of the device's camera to a Wowza Server. I am using Red5 on the device itself to get this done, however I have ran into a multitude of dependency issues. I need to locate the javax.management package with the MXBean class. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That package does not exist in Android, and you cannot reliably add `java.*` or `javax.*` classes to an Android project. That means that you would need to:

1. Write an implementation of `javax.management` and related classes from scratch, calling it `chumlee007.management` or something. You may be able to get some of this code from Apache Harmony, refactoring them into your custom package, but Harmony's implementation of `javax.management` is not complete AFAICT.
2. Modify Red5 to use `chumlee007.management`.

I suspect that you will find it easier to go some other route. AFAIK, Red5 is designed to run on a server, and Android phones are not servers.